# Any idea where I can find every transcript of the FOMC over the years in text?

Tags: programming, fed, fomc

I am trying to scrape each FOMC meeting during the years however I am having trouble finding a repo of the fed that holds all the data.

I finally ended up finding this :
https://www.fedsearch.org/fomc-docs/search?advanced_search=true&from_year=1936&search_precision=All+Words&start=0&sort=Most+Recent+First&to_month=8&to_year=2022&number=10&fomc_document_type=policystatement&Search=Search&text=&from_month=3

However if you have any other source I would be very interested

Comment: This is not a question about Quantitative Finance, more about specific data request.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question

Comment: any idea in which of the stack should I post this question? @Attack68